# Short URL for whatsapp share

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I want to share an article to WhatsApp. Its URL will be like this

```
www.mynewsportal.com/news/myarticle
```

When I share this,the above URL must change to the following format

```
mnp.com/myarticle
```

Also, if I click this link it must redirect to the original URL. Is that possible? Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Something like https://goo.gl/?

Comment: yeah, but it must be custom.

Answer (score 0):

Well the short link is already in use so no, a redirect will not be possible in this case.
But you can specify the url you want to redirect the user to, in the *data-href*

```
<a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="Take a look at this awesome article:" 
data-href="mnp.com/myarticle" class="wa_btn wa_btn_m" style="display:none">My 
news portal - article</a>
```